# Magento with Foundation 5

Tags: magento-1.8

Does anyone know if there is a free Magento Foundation 5 blank theme?

I am using Foundation 5 with a project and I can't seem to use Foundation's javascript plugins.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Jake Sharp's Waterlee theme

http://waterlee.jakesharp.co/